# Vertical alignment of the image within a DIV tag

Tags: html, css, alignment

I have been playing around with div tag for sometime now and i tried doing the rounded corner div tag

```
<div id="y" style="border: 3px solid #000000;background: #b4ef05;
border-radius: 25px;width: 300px; height:200px;">

<div id="ds"style="width:100%; height:80%;border-top-left-radius: 2em;border-top-right-radius:2em; background: #b4ef05;"><span>
<img style="display: block; margin:auto;border: 0 none; position: absolute;left:40px;top:30px;" src="http://www.urbanfonts.com/images/cache/fontnames/1f99582aeadde4d87491dd323d5f01db_auto_362_97.jpg">
</span></div>
<div id="dscs"style="border-bottom-left-radius: 1em;border-bottom-right-radius:1em;width:100%;height:20%;background: #000000;color:#ffffff;"><span style="padding:35px;">sssd</span></div>

</div>
```

[image: output of the above code]

but i am not able to set the image alignment properly, this `vertical-align:middle;` doesn't work.
I need the image to come into the middle of the div automatically deciding the left and top. Also is this approach right to divide the div element into two to store 2 different values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not good to use inline style in html elements :)

**html**

`<img class="imgLackey" src="http://www.urbanfonts.com/images/cache/fontnames/1f99582aeadde4d87491dd323d5f01db_auto_362_97.jpg">`

**css**

```
.imgLackey{
    display: table-cell;
    border: 0 none;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#imgCont{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

#ds{
    display:table;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BDWyP/17/)

Answer (score 1):

Display the parent (`#y`)as a table (`display: table`) and then set the span around the image as a table cell (`display: table-cell`).

This will allow you to use the positioning powers whilst keeping your code semantic.

See this updated codepen:

http://codepen.io/JRKyte/pen/ptaeI

Comment: I tried that too. It does align the image in middle but the top margin is still 0. Only the left margin gets adjusted.

Comment: Just add `left: 50%;` and `margin-left: -116px;` to the code also, i've updated the link for you.

Comment: this does work but the image inside the div tag can change. It could be of varying width and height

Comment: You could try making the margins in percentages as well, i've updated the link, and split the CSS and HTML which is good practise :)

Comment: `#y {
  border: 3px solid #000000;
  background: #b4ef05;
  border-radius: 25px;
  width: 300px; 
  height:200px;
}` change the width and height and it again displaces the image

Comment: Updated the link, use `display: table` on the parent and `display: table-cell` on the image

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `display:table` to the div that contain the image.

Answer (score 0):

To the parent div of this image (id- 'ds') add "position:relative"